BAPI_RE_RO_CHANGE enhancement for custom authorization
I need to implement an authority check through an authorization object whenever calling the BAPI BAPI_RE_RO_CHANGE or changing the unit status from screen REBDRO.
Please explain the steps if this could be done through some type of enhancement in a centralized place for both the standard screen and the BAPI, and if it is not possible please explain how to do it for the BAPI.
Note: the system is ECC.

The list of possible extensions are documented in the SAP Implementation Guide (SPRO).

you wanna do this check against the custom auth object, not standard?
